# The order of a factor group

Tags: group-theory

I'm to find the order of the factor group: $(\mathbb{Z}_{11} \times \mathbb{Z}_{15})/<(1,1)>$. I thought the idea was calculating the number of elements in $(\mathbb{Z}_{11} \times \mathbb{Z}_{15})$ and dividing that by the number of elements generated by $<1,1>$ in $(\mathbb{Z}_{11} \times \mathbb{Z}_{15})$ and this case have it be $11*15/11*15=1$ (since, 11 and 15 are coprimes). But my answer sheet says the order of the factor group is 0. Is the answer sheet wrong or have I misunderstood something? (Also: is it generally frowned upon to ask questions like this?)

Comment: No group has order $0,$ since it at least has an identity element. This applies to factor groups in particular.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The answer sheet is wrong. No group has order $0$. Every group has an identity element, hence has order at least $1$, which is the correct answer in this case.